# Azure Cosmos ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync returns error: "ResourceType Collection is unexpected"

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, runtime-error, azure-cosmosdb

Cosmos client Version=3.19.0.0

The code is taken from microsoft docs, exactly like it is. [check the example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.scripts.scripts.executestoredprocedureasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Let me display it again:

```
   string sprocBody = @"function simple(prefix, postfix)
   {
       var collection = getContext().getCollection();

       // Query documents and take 1st item.
       var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
           collection.getSelfLink(),
           'SELECT * FROM root r',
           function(err, feed, options) {
               if (err)throw err;

               // Check the feed and if it's empty, set the body to 'no docs found',
               // Otherwise just take 1st element from the feed.
               if (!feed || !feed.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody(""no docs found"");
               else getContext().getResponse().setBody(prefix + JSON.stringify(feed[0]) + postfix);
           });

       if (!isAccepted) throw new Error(""The query wasn't accepted by the server. Try again/use continuation token between API and script."");
   }";

Scripts scripts = this.container.Scripts;
string sprocId = "appendString";
StoredProcedureResponse storedProcedureResponse = await scripts.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(
        sprocId,
        sprocBody);

// Execute the stored procedure
StoredProcedureExecuteResponse<string> sprocResponse = await scripts.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(
                        sprocId,
                        new PartitionKey("userId"),
                        new dynamic[] {"myPrefixString", "myPostfixString"});
```

**ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync** returns error: **ResourceType Collection is unexpected**

Anybody else got this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, it was a problem with how I instantiated my Container(I provided an un-existing containerId, and no errors were raised) ... soo sad